# How to customize dash parameter when NaNs present

Tags: python, matplotlib

If possible, I prefer to avoid using colors in line plots, mainly to be considerate of colorblind people.  However, python has only four built-in line styles, so anything with more than four lines needs a custom dash patter.  This becomes problematic when NaN values are present (see figure -- which presents an extreme example that carefully positions NaNs in the middle of alternate dashes).

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 100)
y = np.arange(0, 100)
nans = np.arange(0, 100, dtype=float)
nans[::10] = np.nan

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(3.25, 2.5))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax0.plot(x, y, dashes=[8, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4])
ax0.plot(nans, y - 25, dashes=[8, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4])

ax0.legend(("without NaNs", "with NaNs"), loc=2, fontsize=8)
```

[image]

Both lines should have the same pattern.  However, because of the NaN values they do not.
Of course, I could filter my arrays to remove NaNs, but I wonder if there is another workaround to give both lines the same dash patter.

Comment: I've edited this to make it clear this is an extreme example. Otherwise, it presents as an unnecessary puzzle to people trying to understand your question.

Comment: Overall, I'd suggest that dashes should be used only if they are significantly shorted than the structures in the data. NaNs are structures in the data, and if they are not, it seems reasonable to remove them from the data before plotting. This would be one line of code in both pandas and numpy.